# Laravel API Generator

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, crud

I have a project and I'm only responsible for the Back-End development.
In the Back-End I have to create an API that generally have CRUD operations, and the problem is that they are a lot, so to explain exactly here is an example:

Demand => Create a CRUD for `Article(Id:number, Title:string, Thumbnail:picture, Content:text, Tags:text)`

Explanation => I have to create everything needed so the Front-end can send requests to Create, Read, List, Update or Delete an Article (Return data as JSON)

Problem => I'm searching for a package or a tool that generates that automatically, knowing that a request could contain files or pictures not only text data.

**Please Don't Forget**

- I'm not seeking for a view generator [I'm not working for the Front-End] I'm only responsible for the Back-End
- Everything I need do exist in other frameworks, but I want to work with Laravel
- I wish you give me tools or packages that you have used not from Google searches because I'm searching for the 4th day
- I found this http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/ but it seems that it have a little bit complicated documentation (Maybe the problem in me)
- I'm using Laravel 5

Comment: Searching for off-site resources like packages is *off-topic*. Anyway, I'd suggest you to look into [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers). That'd reduce the work a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me what you're looking for.  Regarding routes and controllers, Laravel's built-in functionality for [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) is quite useful in providing general REST scaffolding.  If you're interested in all the details of implementing CRUD-like functionality, that's a more involved topic and I'd advise spending some time reading through Laravel's fairly comprehensive [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4).

Answer (score 3):

There are several great options for automatic generation of api in laravel you can checkout [Dreamfactory](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dreamfactory), [infyom](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator) or [apiato](https://github.com/apiato/apiato), I recommend infyom if you have a small project and you need simple api.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, Veeeeeeeeeeeery USEFUL

Answer (score 1):

Try [Laravel API/Scaffold/CRUD Generator](https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator)

Comment: This one is deprecated and I'm no longer maintaining it. so the use of InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator is recommended.